# React native open modal into a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

- How to open modal from the modal box in react native.
  ex: I have one form in modal and one color picker field into the form so how can I open color picker to another modal.

`Name: XYZ 
Age: 21 
Color: A (This is the color picker. When I click the text open color picker in modal)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render the nested color modal inside the outer modal as content, the visibility of nested modal will depend on the `click/press` over the `text`. Consider the sample code below, for demonstration purpose, I have used [react-native-color-picker](https://github.com/instea/react-native-color-picker) library, you can use any other library as well.

**Sample**

Initializing state variable, `outerModalVisible` controls the visibility of outer modal and `nestedModalVisible` controls the visibility of nested modal. In the sample code, `outerModalVisible` value remain `true` but you can change it as per your requirement.

```
state={
  outerModalVisible: true,
  nestedModalVisible: false,
  selected_color: '#fff'
}
```

In render method, defining the outer model and nested modal

```
<View>
    <Modal visible={this.state.outerModalVisible} >
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Name: XYZ</Text>
        <Text>Age: 21</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{
          this.setState({
            nestedModalVisible: true
          });
        }}>
          <Text>Color picker: {this.state.selected_color}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.nestedModalVisible}
        >
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <ColorPicker
            onColorSelected={color => {
              this.setState({
                selected_color: color,
                nestedModalVisible: false
              });
            }}
            style={{flex: 1}}
          />
            <Button title="click to close" onPress={() =>{
              this.setState({
                nestedModalVisible: false
              });
            }} />
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  </View>
```

You may define the content of nested model in a separate component, I just keep it simple and defined it inside a single component.

Hope this will help!